# I'm trying to create a program that reads information from a text file and sends it to 2 matrix tables. How do i fix it?

Tags: arrays

```
The file contains:
matrix 
row
-1
2
-2
0
row
-3
4
7
2
row
6
0
3
1
matrix
row
-1
3
row
0
9
row
1
-11
row
4
-5
```

This information needs to be sent to a matrix table, or 2D array.
This is the information being sent to the file reader.
This is the code I have so far:

```
public class MatrixTester {

public static int[][] mResult;

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * @throws java.io.IOException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    String fileName;
    fileName = "C:\\Users\\Adam\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\MatrixTester\\MatrixData.txt";


    int a[][] = new int[3][4];
    int b[][] = new int[4][2];


    String line = " ";

    FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);

    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(fr);

    int lineCount = 0;

    String[] numbers = (bf.readLine()).split("\n");


        while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null)
        {
            numbers = line.split(" ");

                    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)  
                        {
                            // Get line values
                            String[] values = numbers[i].split("\n");

                            String delims = "0123456789";
                            StringTokenizer integers = new StringTokenizer(values[i], delims);

                            while(integers.hasMoreTokens())
                            {
                                integers.nextToken();

                                for(int j = 0; j < values.length; j++) 
                                    {

                                    for(int k = 0; k < lineCount; k++)
                                        {
                                            // Punt in Matrix
                                            a[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(values[j]);
                                            lineCount++;
                                        }
                                    }
                            }
            }



            /*
            */
        }

        bf.close();


    //Outputting information.
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a) + "\t");
}   
}
```

The code I have so far should send the information to the first 2D array, I have not gotten to the second array yet. The output I get for the code thus far is [[0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0]].
How do I fix this?

Comment: Please don't ask us to do your work for you. Try something and, if it doesn't work, come back to us with a _specific_ problem.

Comment: It looks like you should be using the numpy library for handling matrices.  If you can change your file format to be just an array of numbers, separated by commas, for example, then the whole reading operation is a single line: numpy.loadtxt(...)